# Debugging Karate Using Karate Runner and Gradle Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, karate

As Gradle has defaulted their build file to use Kotlin, and I've never been a fan of Groovy, trying to get debugging working using the open source `Karate Runner` (v1.2.5).  I've tried a few versions of the `karateExecute` task, none of them seem to work.  From the Karate Runner docs I see:

```
tasks.register<JavaExec>("karateExecute") {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.get().runtimeClasspath
    main.set(System.getProperty("mainClass"))
}
```

However that returns the following error when running `gradle init`:

```
 main.set(System.getProperty("mainClass"))
               ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                   public val SourceSetContainer.main: NamedDomainObjectProvider<SourceSet> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

Open JDK 17

Gradle 8.5

Karate 1.4.1

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    `java`
    `maven-publish`
}

val karateVersion by extra("1.4.1")

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.com.github.javafaker.javafaker){exclude ( "org.yaml")} 
    implementation (group= "org.yaml", name= "snakeyaml", version= "2.0")
    testImplementation("com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:${karateVersion}")
}      

group = "com.mycompany"
version = "0.1"
description = "karatePoc"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
        from(components["java"])
    }
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>() {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

tasks.withType<Javadoc>() {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir(file("src/test/java"))
            exclude("**/*.java")
        }
    }
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("karate.options", System.getProperty("karate.options"))
    systemProperty("karate.env", System.getProperty("karate.env"))
    outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
}

// task<JavaExec>("karateDebug") {
//     mainClass.set("com.intuit.karate.cli.Main")
//     classpath = sourceSets["test"].runtimeClasspath
// }

tasks.register<JavaExec>("karateExecute") {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.get().runtimeClasspath
    main.set(System.getProperty("mainClass"))
}
```

Comment: karate 1.4.1 has a separate dependency for the debug-server: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Debug-Server

Comment: Java doesn't like something between the `build.gradle.kts` and the `launch.json` command.  I get `Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of v1.4.1 Karate has moved their open source server side debug code inside a proprietary dependency.  See this commit:
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/commit/0d49e81e2964fb2de3ad6d90274312f4f319bf87

```
 > Task :karateExecute FAILED 14:00:24.224 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - Karate version: 1.4.1 error: IDE debug requires paid upgrade of the Karate Labs plugin / extension
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a deprecated API there. See `setMain()` in [`JavaExecSpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/process/JavaExecSpec.html).

That means should first replace that line with:

```
mainClass.set(System.getProperty("mainClass"))
```

However, the [Karate docs](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Gradle) specify the main class as `com.intuit.karate.cli.Main` so I suspect you should actually use:

```
mainClass.set("com.intuit.karate.cli.Main")
```

Comment: That's what I was using originally, but had tried it to `main.set()`.  `main = System.getProperty("mainClass")`, which is what's specified in the Karate Runner docs.  But that also returns the same error.

Comment: You need to run gradle with the --stacktrace option to see what the new error is.

Comment: I did that, but didn't see anything helpful, added above.

Comment: Hmmm that is the stacktrace of the Gradle process but you need the stacktrace of the underlying JVM process that it starts. When I do that on mine it is printed to console, before "Build failed with an exception". Is it possible your console doesn't receive System.err?

Comment: Added this line to my gradle build fille `logging.captureStandardOutput(LogLevel.DEBUG)`, and now I get:
`> Task :karateExecute FAILED
14:00:24.224 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - Karate version: 1.4.1
error: IDE debug requires paid upgrade of the Karate Labs plugin / extension`

Comment: I tried your build and got it working with the main class name specified as a string. See amended answer

Comment: Docs differ between Karate Core, and Karate Runner.  If you look at the update section I have tried that.  It works fine with the `gradle clean test` command.  Error is only when attempting to run debugger, which works for this version of Karate and Maven, so I suspect the error telling me to I have to pay for debugging using the open source Karate Runner is a defect.  Opened a issue with Karate Runner git repo to verify.